# Uncaught TypeError: Masonry.init is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have been trying to implement a Bootstrap theme (Megakit) (http://keenthemes.com/preview/megakit/) into my rails app.

Now I have been using the basic method: Copying the HTML/CSS/SCSS then the Javascript into the right folders.

Most of the website works great but I'm having a problem with Mansonry and I don't really understand what happens (Javascript is not my strong suit).

```
 masonry.self-f70335ff283115f92d456ed8fba03b11890ff509c5c5964a0ab3207c7183f53a.js?body=1:44 
Uncaught TypeError: Masonry.init is not a function
        at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (masonry.self-f70335ff283115f92d456ed8fba03b11890ff509c5c5964a0ab3207c7183f53a.js?body=1:44)
        at fire (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3233)
        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3363)
        at Function.ready (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3583)
        at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3618)
```

Which makes no sense to me since I have basically just copied the files from a folder and it was working there.

my masonry.js file (not the vendor one) where it apparently does not work.

```
// Masonry
var Masonry = function() {
  'use strict';

  // Handle Masonry
  var handleMasonry = function() {
    var $container = $('.js__masonry');
    // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.js__masonry-item', // use a separate class for itemSelector, other than .col-
        columnWidth: '.js__masonry-sizer',
        percentPosition: true
      });
    });
    $.fn.masonryImagesReveal = function( $items ) {
      var msnry = this.data('masonry');
      var itemSelector = msnry.options.itemSelector;
      // hide by default
      $items.hide();
      // append to container
      this.append( $items );
      $items.imagesLoaded().progress( function( imgLoad, image ) {
        // get item
        // image is imagesLoaded class, not <img>, <img> is image.img
        var $item = $( image.img ).parents( itemSelector );
        // un-hide item
        $item.show();
        // masonry does its thing
        msnry.appended( $item );
      });
      return this;
    };
  }

  return {
    init: function() {
      handleMasonry(); // initial setup for Masonry
    }
  }
}();

$(document).ready(function() {
  Masonry.init();
});
```

Could you tell me what is possibly going on / happening?
Thank you,

Anthony

Comment: blease wrap your function in parentheses: `var Masonry = (function() { /* ... */})()`

Comment: Jea but it bothers me. The error indicates that the code gets parsed and executed without error, but it should throw an error at the `()` and Masonry should therefor be undefined and the `Masonry.init();` should never be called.. But apparently the function gets assigned to Masonry. really strange this one..

Comment: Thanks for you answers. 

Unfortunately it does not change much.

Could it be some kind of dysfunction with Jquery? I believe mansonry relies on it ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it's pure luck, but I solved it by changing the Masonry.init by :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 200
});
});
```

Hope that helps